# Make system with ultrasonic sensor and servo

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, servo

I want to create a system where the servo will make the ultrasonic sensor move and detect the area in front of it. I have made the program but when run the ultrasonic sensor can not detect as usual.

Does anyone have another program or why my program is not running as planned?

This is the source code :

```
#include <Servo.h> 

const int trigPin = 10;
const int echoPin = 9;
int lampu = 13 ;

// membuat nama objek servo untuk pengontrolan servo 
Servo myservo;          
// variable untuk menyimpan posisi servo 
int pos = 0;
long duration, inches, cm;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(lampu, OUTPUT);
  myservo.attach(7);   
}

void loop() {
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  inches = microsecondsKeInchi(duration);
  cm = microsecondsKeCenti(duration);
  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print(" in, ");
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print(" cm");
  Serial.println();

  lampuNyala() ;
  servo();
  delay(10);        
}

// start dari 0 derajar sampai 180 derajat 
long microsecondsKeInchi(long microseconds)
{
  return microseconds / 74 / 2;
}

long microsecondsKeCenti(long microseconds)
{
  return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}       

void servo(){
  for(pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 1)  
  {
    // pada posisi 1 derajat
    // memberitahu servo untuk pergi ke posisi  'pos'
    myservo.write(pos);
    // tunggu 15ms untuk pencapaian  posisi servo    
    delay(30);   
  } 
  // start dari 180 derajat ke 0 derajat 
  for(pos = 180; pos>=1; pos-=1)  
  {
    // memberitahu servo untuk pergi ke posisi  'pos'                                
    myservo.write(pos);                 
    // tunggu 15ms untuk pencapaian  posisi servo    
    delay(30);    
  }
}

void lampuNyala(){
  if(cm > 0 && cm <=30){
    digitalWrite(lampu,HIGH) ;
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(lampu,LOW) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments in English would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code sequence. An ultrasonic measurement is only taken, when you use `pulseIn()`. At the end of the `loop()` function you call your `servo()` function. In it you tell the Arduino to first go from 0° to 180° and then back to 0°. AFTER THAT (!) the function exits and the `loop()` function continues. This means, that nothing else happens during the servo motion. The measurement only takes place between the motions, meaning about every 10s.

To solve this problem you need to make the servo code non-blocking. It is mostly a bad thing to use `delay()`, since you cannot do anything else during waiting. Think about how you are backing a pizza. You are not sitting in front of the oven the whole time, until the pizza is ready. Instead you are looking at your clock regularily and check, if it is time to take the pizza out of the oven.

You can do the same thing on an Arduino with the `millis()` function. It will return the milliseconds since the last reset/powerup of the Arduino. This has to be used as a clock. To do something after a specific time you first save the current time in a timestamp:

```
unsigned long timestamp=0;
...
timestamp = millis();
```

Then in the `loop()` function you are regularly (on every loop iteration) checking, if the difference between the timestamp and the current time is above your set interval:

```
if(millis() - timestamp > 30){
    // do something here, like moving a servo
    timestamp = millis(); //update timestamp for next event
}
```

The Arduino will not do the things simultaneously, but will switch between the different code parts so fast, that it will seem simultaneous. Also refer to the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example of the Arduino library.

Note: The current delay between two consecutive servo values is ok. If you want to go way faster with the servo, you have to watch out, that the rest of the code in `loop()` doesn't take to long. If this happens and you cannot make the other code parts non-blocking too, you can also do the servo part in an interrupt routine from a timer.